# How to escape characters for dictionary key values in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to assign value to a dictionary key but getting an error

```
"ValueError: Adding data to a dictionary failed. There should be even number of key-value-pairs."
```

Here is the code

```
   set to dictionary    ${cParamsDict}    cust_params    v=classifieds&cpage=browseads&article-id=65207
```

I believe the "=" in the value is causing issue. How do I resolve this? I have to pass this dictionary to a keyword for further verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Set To Dictionary    ${cParamsDict}    cust_params    v\=classifieds&cpage\=browseads&article-id\=65207
```

or

```
${value}    Set Variable    v=classifieds&cpage=browseads&article-id=65207
Set To Dictionary    ${cParamsDict}    cust_params    ${value}
```

Docu: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify - you've already created a dictionary using the [Create Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20Dictionary) keyword (from Built-in)?

If so, then yes - likely as not your issue is not escaping embedded equals signs. Your line should read like this:

```
Set To Dictionary    ${cParamsDict}    cust_params=v\=classifieds&cpage\=browseads&article-id\=65207
```

Read up on [escaping in the documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping).